# Run Google Apps Script in background

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, background, gmail

I have a spreadsheet where I paste data in one sheet then run an Apps Script that parses, sorts, and send emails with attachments. I have about 300 lines of code and currently it takes about 5-10 minutes to run if I leave the sheet open. When I try to move to other tabs in google,or try to compose a message in gmail and what not, I get the error message "unable to load file" and I have to reload, stopping the script.

My spreadsheet has about 15 sheets, each with a filter formula in each. There are tons of get and set range values.

Is there any easy way to compose a script and the sheet so I can paste the data into it, then close the sheet and still have the script run in the background?

Comment: Google Apps Script run on Google's servers. Do your script does a lot of get/set or your spreadsheet has a lot of formulas?

Comment: My spreadsheet has about 15 sheets, each with a filter formula in each. There are tons of get and set range values yes.

Comment: Consider to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing the "unable load file" error message as there isn't code include in the question but it's worth to note that some Spreadsheet Services methods take data from the active sheet or from the active range. If your script uses these methods and you click on a different sheet/range that provide the data required by the script that could make that the script produce unexpected results.

By the other side, Google Apps Script run on the Google's Servers but formula recalculation occurs on the user environment if your device doesn't have enough resources to handle your spreadsheet recalculation could the the cause of the problem.

Comment: Okay thanks. I think it may also be happening when I try sending an email from my gmail account at the same time, since the script uses the GmailApp library. I'll look up how to run the script while using Gmail at the same time.